# How to use Puma with SSL and chained certificates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, ssl-certificate, puma

I cannot seem to figure out how to correctly use Puma with SSL and intermediate certificates.

Everything works fine in for example the Chrome browser, but fails in for example Android, because it is able to pull the intermediate and root certificates from somewhere else.

It seems I am unable to supply the intermediate and root certificates correctly.

In Apache2 I was able to get the chain to work by supplying the client-crt, the key and the ca-bundle(interm. #1, interm. #2 and the root certificate).

This is how I start the Puma Server:

```
puma -e production -b 'ssl://SERVER_IP:443?key=ssl/key&cert=ssl/chained-crt' -t 4:16 -b 'tcp://SERVER_IP:80'
```

The "chained-crt" chain looks like this:

1. Client
2. Intermediate #1
3. Intermediate #2
4. Root

The "key" only holds the key.

When I try wget I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The certificate of `redacted' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of `redacted' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

Version Numbers:

```
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.2.3
puma version 2.11.1
```

SSLShopper's SSL-Test says the following, however as I said above I have no problems getting the chain and the bespoke test to pass using Apache2:

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to
>   install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root
>   certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by
>   following Comodo's Certificate Installation Instructions for your
>   server platform (use these instructions for InstantSSL). Pay attention
>   to the parts about Intermediate certificates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Humor me here... So I'm assuming your chained certificate you're using contains 3 parts: the two intermediate certificates, and the root certificate? And then separately you're using your site certificate?

Comment: The chained certificate contains the site certificate, the two intermediate certificates and the root certificate - in that order.

Comment: Who is the provider of your SSL cert, if I can ask? I assume Comodo since that's in the question?

Comment: Yes Comodo but like i said it works using Apache2 by specifying the site-crt, key and bundle-ca, i doubt it matters but it is an SSL EV certificate.

Comment: Maybe I'm suggesting something stupid, but just for kicks, have you tried changing the order of the two intermediate certificates in the chain file? And, I'm assuming your cert isn't expired, correct?

Comment: Not yet, i just took them off of Comodos site but i will try that right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88909/discussion-between-josh-beam-and-susan).

Comment: The site certificate is valid yes and like I said everything is working using Apache2 instead of Puma.

Comment: @Susan, I encountered the same issue, but decided to work around it by using Nginx with puma.